# NSCollectionView How to scroll to selected item

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview, nscollectionview

I programmatically select a item in my NSCollectionView. The item is selected as expected but the view doesn't scroll automatically to this item.

```
[collectionView setSelectionIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:compt]];
```

How to scroll to the selected item ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the answer here [NSScrollView: Make sure frame is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143915/nsscrollview-make-sure-frame-is-visible)

This code worked for me :

```
NSRect selectionRect = [self.collectionView frameForItemAtIndex:[[self.collectionView selectionIndexes] firstIndex]];
[self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:selectionRect];
```

Answer (score 5):

Tested on: Swift 4.2. Xcode 10.2. macOS 10.14.5 Beta

```
if  let indexPath = indexPaths.first {
            if #available(OSX 10.12, *) {
                NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { (context) in
                    context.duration = 0.8
                    context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
                    collectionView.scrollToItems(at: [indexPath], scrollPosition: NSCollectionView.ScrollPosition.bottom)
                }
            } else {
                collectionView.scrollToItems(at: [indexPath], scrollPosition: NSCollectionView.ScrollPosition.bottom)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since OS X 10.11 in the new NSCollectionView you should use instead:

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemsAtIndexPaths:[self.collectionView selectionIndexPaths] scrollPosition:NSCollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally];
```

Answer (score 0):

let scrollPositionX: CGFloat = videoThumbCollectionView.visibleRect.origin.x + 150.0
        videoThumbCollectionView.scroll(NSPoint(x: scrollPositionX, y: videoThumbCollectionView.visibleRect.origin.y))

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4

```
collectionView.scrollToItems(at: [collectionView.selectionIndexPaths.first!], scrollPosition: NSCollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select and scroll with animation at the same time, you can use this (Swift):

```
 NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { (context) in
     context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
     collectionView.selectItems(at: [newIndexPath], scrollPosition: .centeredVertically)
 }
```